# Flutter reminder app alarm notification return value

Tags: flutter, notifications, reminders, flutter-notification

I am writing a reminder application using flutter. I want it to send notifications for the tasks entered at that date and time, even if the application is closed. Its notification should be like the phone's default alarm app. Confirmation snooze buttons and sounds. I'll need what the user did with this notification on another page. I am not using a database. Is there an easy way to do these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) or [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

`flutter_local_notifications` example

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    'scheduled title',
    'scheduled body',
    tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
    const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
```

`awesome_notifications` example

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
      id: id,
      channelKey: 'scheduled',
      title: 'wait 5 seconds to show',
      body: 'now is 5 seconds later',
      wakeUpScreen: true,
      category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,
  ),
  schedule: NotificationInterval(
      interval: 5,
      timeZone: localTimeZone,
      preciseAlarm: true,
      timezone: await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier()
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the `awesome-notifications` package!**

- Package on pub.dev:- https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications
- To install the package, use the command:-

```sh
flutter pub add awesome-notifications
```